# iOS audio conference research

Tags: ios, xmppframework, google-talk

I'm new to voice and audio over a network.
I've been searching on google for samples and solutions to implement a p2p voice connection (the idea was an audio conference).

I found google talk xmpp framework that can access informations like users and text chatting.
Does anyone have any idea for this framework if is used to implement a voice chat or some things like conferencing?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [hoiio](http://developer.hoiio.com/)  (it works for whole country)

The other options were tropo, pilvo and twilio (it doesn't work for some country).

Comment: I'm looking to understand the global architecture for this voice server and how it turn :/ !